# Set cover problem - existence of a set with atleast $n_t /k$ uncovered items

Tags: algorithms

Claim: Suppose $B$ contains $n$ elements and that the optimal cover consists of $k$ sets. Then the
greedy algorithm will use at most $k \ ln(n)$ sets.

Let $n_t$ be the number of elements still not covered after $t$ iterations of the greedy algorithm
(so $n_0 = n$). **Since these remaining elements are covered by the optimal $k$ sets, there must be some set with at least $n_t /k$ of them.**

Here, I do not understand the bold line i.e. where did we get the $n_t /k$ from?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the claim is not true: that would mean that every set $S_i$ of the $k$ optimal sets has some number $q_i$ of the uncovered elements, but $q_i < n_t/k$.  If we total the number of uncovered elements in our $k$ optimal sets, we have:

$$\sum_{1 \leq i \leq k} q_i < \sum_{1 \leq i \leq k} \frac{n_t}{k} < \frac{n_t}{k} \cdot k < n_t$$

in other words, less than the number of uncovered elements.  This contradicts the fact that the $k$ optimal sets cover the elements.

Here's something analogous:  If you have $k$ numbers, but each number is strictly less than $100/k$, then it's impossible for those numbers to sum to $100$.